# Picking a specific estimated CDF from a set of CDFs provided by an ECDF

Tags: sampling, nonparametric, central-limit-theorem, cumulative-distribution-function, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Let $F_X$ be a CDF of an unknown random variable $X$. If we have independent samples $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ of $X$ then we can estimate $F_X$ non-parametrically using an ECDF $\hat{F}_n$. By Central Limit Theorem, for each $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$

$$\sqrt{n}(\hat{F_n}(x_i) - F_X(x_i)) \rightarrow N(0,F_X(x_i)[1-F_X(x_i)])$$

**What I want to know :** How to pick one estimated CDF using the distribution above?

Aside from $\hat{F}_n$, I'm also interested in other estimated CDFs based on the distribution per $x$. Independent sampling for each $x$ will most likely violate the non-decreasing requirement of a CDF and exceed the range $[0,1]$.

If we do this parametrically, I just need the likelihood of each parameter given the samples then use a sampling method to pick a specific set parameters to get the CDF. However, I don't have any clue what the distribution is so I'm using a non-parametric approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are operating under some misapprehensions here.  Firstly, we estimate unknown things from *the data we have*, not from data we might have gotten instead.  Every statistical estimator is a function that maps all possible data vectors we can observe to the space of possible values of the thing we are estimating --- we obtain the *estimate* by substituting the *observed data* into this function.  So the estimator to use is the empirical CDF of the observed data.

Secondly, you will also find that irrespective of the data, the ECDF is always a valid distribution function (i.e., it is always non-decreasing, right-continuous, etc.).  This is guaranteed by the form:

$$\hat{F}_n(x) \equiv \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{I}(x_i \leqslant x).$$

It is simple to establish that this function satisfies the requirements of a distribution function for all $\mathbf{x}_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$, so you are incorrect to think that any of these properties will be violated merely because the sample values are IID given the underlying distribution function $F$.

Now, you are correct that the CLT gives the asymptotic normal distribution you have stated.    A small variation in this statement allows you to get a [pivotal quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity) for the estimation problem, which will allow you to form a confidence interval for $F(x)$ using the estimated value $\hat{F}_n(x)$.  This is essentially just a confidence interval for a proportion using binomial data, so standard forms apply.  (There are a number of different forms for confidence intervals for binomial proportions, but I am a fan of the [Wilson score interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval).)  That is what we use this distributional result for --- it does not imply that we would use a different set of data for the estimate than the data that is actually observed.

Comment: The CDF is already made and for each value of x, Fhat(x) is approximately normal. What I meant by independent sampling is per x, we will sample from that normal distribution and produce other CDFs possible but doing that will most likely violate the definition of CDF.